# Kendo editor does not show vertical scrollbar if prefilled with overflowing content

Tags: kendo-ui, editor

I use the kendo editor for a textarea element which I prefill with text that overflows. The editor is rendered inside a kendo wizard.

```
<textarea id="editor"></textarea>

$("#editor").kendoEditor({
    value: "<p>New content</p><p>New content</p><p>New content</p><p>New content</p><p>New content</p><p>New content</p><p>New content</p><p>New content</p><p>New content</p>"
});
```

No vertical scrollbar appears although scrolling in the text field is possible. The scrollbar only appears once I start to edit the text. Is it possible to show the vertical scrollbar initially?

Comment: What browser is this happening on? I put your code in a dojo and it works fine on Chrome, FF, Edge, and IE 11: http://dojo.telerik.com/IhASI . Are you sure the problem is not caused by styling, which the textarea is inheriting from its parents or something?

Comment: I use Chrome. Yes, maybe this is caused by some styling.

Comment: can you tell which element controls the overflow?

Comment: The Kendo Editor renders an iframe. The <body> element inside the iframe is the owner of the scroll bar. I think it uses the k-content class out of kendo.default.css, but I am not 100% sure. Are you doing anything that will change the height of your textarea?

Comment: no, I don't change the height.